# How do I fix pwd (print working directory) on Cyanogenmod 7?

Tags: cyanogenmod, ssh, busybox

I want to use WinSCP to transfer data to my phone over wireless. I've enabled dropbear on my phone.  WinSCP connects, but crashes after trying `pwd`.  Logging in with PuTTy, I can see that `pwd` is returning a [blank line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eZmm.png):

```
/data/dropbear # pwd

/data/dropbear # which pwd
/system/xbin/pwd
/data/dropbear # busybox pwd
/data/dropbear
/data/dropbear # ls -l /system/xbin/pwd
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Apr  1 23:30 pwd -> busybox
```

Coming from an OpenWrt background, that dropbear setup seems normal to me.  Why is this shell printing blank lines?  My device is a Motorola Droid running Cyanogenmod 7 RC4.

Comment: What do you get if you just run busybox without any parameters? It looks like that's what's happening on your first line, since as you say, pwd is just a link to busybox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you replace the pwd symbolic link with a script that just runs 'busybox pwd'?

Or would an alias work?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is different because `dropbear` [uses a different shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pvfl.png) than the [terminal app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PV7T.png).  A workaround would be to just use the same shell as the terminal app:

```
echo "/system/bin/sh" > /data/dropbear/.profile
```

Be advised that this contradicts the [Cyanogenmod wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Howto:_Connect_to_Device_with_SSH), which instructs you to use the busybox shell: `/system/xbin/busybox sh`